# ipad this WORKS with breakpoints in and doesn't without... :/

Tags: ipad, uitableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


    }
```

this seems to work with a break point on the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` line, but when I take it out I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS and a crash. NO idea why - its the default code in there for a TableViewController - I added some code and it didn't work. Put break points in and it turned out it was that line, so stripped it right down to the original code and it still doesn't work! :( Argh...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This feels like a race condition to me. My guess is that some row you are deleting is being used right up until deletion, so without the breakpoint you are deleting it too soon. With the breakpoint, the delay is long enough that the row is finished being used.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it wasn't this unfortunately - it was a silly error... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete a row in a tableView `numberOfRowsInSection` needs to update to return the number of rows before deleting the row minus 1, or else you get this ambiguous crash.